# Grade build compile gives dependency error

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

Hey guys im making an app in kotlin with jetpack compose but when i run the app its gives me this error.

"Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
> Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:0.1.0-dev07.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/0.1.0-dev07/compiler-0.1.0-dev07.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/0.1.0-dev07/compiler-0.1.0-dev07.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/0.1.0-dev07/compiler-0.1.0-dev07.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
  "

This is my code(build-gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.zsoltk.pokedex"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev07"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1"
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev07'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev07'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev07'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev07'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev07'
    implementation 'com.github.zsoltk:compose-router:0.7.0'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.17"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.61"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any ideia of what i need to do?

Comment: You should update all dependencies to use the latest 1.0.0-beta05

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the dependency it demands?

One needs this Gradle plugin:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.compiler/compiler

And these are the Java dependencies:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose

```
implementation "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:0.1.0-dev17"
```

It's meanwhile `dev17` and not `dev7`.

Comment: Hello, i try do add that dependecy, and i changed all to dev17 but stills giving me the error

Comment: You never apply the plugin  and one `build.gradle` is missing; therefore: good luck.

Comment: already put the other build.gradle. and i added the plugin but dont work